# xamarin forms notify property changed not working with IOS listview

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms

I have a list of images being displayed in a listview  with a button that allows the user to add a photo to the list using the Media plugin for xamarin by James montemagno

List XAML

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Images}"
              x:Name="lsvImages"
              HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImgSource}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

When the image is added it is saved as a byte array in an object. that object is added to the list and it fires the notify property change event for Images

```
 PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Images"));
```

This works perfectly in android, take a picture and the list updates as expected. In IOS the images gets created added to the list of images, the property changed event fires but the listview does not update, it never even hits the getter for ImgSource. If i flip the Iphone to landscape and back again it works.

I have fixed it temporarily by setting the items source of the listview to null then rebinding it again but I don't get why it works for android but not IOS.

Comment: have you tried using an ObservableCollection instead?  That will automatically update the ListView when an item is added.

Comment: @Jason that works so if you want to post it I'll accept it as an answer but I would still be interested in knowing why the property changed worked fine on android but not IOS

Comment: Not sure, but it's probably due to some underlying difference in how ListViews are implemented on each platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `ObservableCollection` instead of a `List`.  ObservableCollection implements INotifyCollectionChanged so it will automatically notify the ListView of any additions or deletions from the data source.